# How to know how much time is left for the Alarm

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my application I have a button that sets a determined time to run the `AlarmManager`, and I need to show how much time is left for the alarm in one `TextView`, how can I do that?

**NOTE**: My app need to work in API 15.

Button that starts the `AlarmManager`:

```
// Alarm manager
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        buttonsTimer.get(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+42000000, pendingIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to store the start time:

```
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+42000000;
```

Then to find the time remaining on the alarm, just subtract the current time from the start time:

```
long timeRemaining= startTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This will make `timeRemaining` contain the time left before the alarm goes off, in milliseconds.  Then just set that to a `TextView` with `setText()`.

Comment: Thank you, it is so simple but i stuck with this.